# Could and Could Have + P.P

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I am very confused with usage of could and could have +p.p.

For example, do these sentences mean the same:

1. *I couldn't come to college last week.*
2. *I couldn't have come to college last week.*
3. *I couldn't have come to college last week because I was working.*

I know that could refers to ability to do something, while could have + p.p refers to some possibility in the past. However, in the examples above there is no difference because they bear the same meaning to me:

1. *I was not able to come to college last week.*
2. *I was not able to come to college last week because I was working.*

Another confusing examples would be:

1. *This book could not be written without your help. (Here I'm speaking about the past, not about the future.)*
2. *This book could not have been written without your help.*

And one more:
"If she couldn't have come to my party, I wouldn't have invited her."

Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider also that couldn't have may refer to a condition that was averted: *I couldn't have come to college last week if you hadn't let me use your car.*

Comment: @vpalyX Your question has already been extensively answered here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121293/could-and-could-have-p-p

Comment: @Guastavson Yes, thank you very much! That is actually my question. Could you post your answer here? Thus I can ask you some questions because I can't comment answers on that page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cross posting is not allowed.

Comment: @vpaliyX if you have lost access to the account at ELL, the best course of action is to [contact the community team](https://ell.stackexchange.com/contact), rather than cross post to another SE site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"1: I couldn't come to college last week" is similar to "2: I couldn't have come to college last week." The difference is easiest to see if you know why we would say one over the other.

You were sick. Did you get here in the last few days?

> Sorry, *I couldn't come to college last week.* (As a simple statement of fact, I could not travel there for some reason, any reason.)

I thought I saw you here in class.

> You are wrong. *I couldn't have come to college last week.* (It was impossible for me to travel there, and I certainly did not travel. Arguing tone shows what you say is impossible, it could not be true.) The meaning does not change much for adding an explanation (*3: because I was working*).

"This book could not have been written without your help" is in the past.

"This book could not be written without your help" is more general, not necessarily in the past.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However, is it fine if I use "This book could not be written without your help" as a reference to the past? Or  that is absolutely wrong and it would be better to use "This book could not have been written without your help" ?

Comment: 'Could not be written' is vague. Has the book been written? If so, then it has been written, and you show appreciation by saying 'could not have been written without your help.'